# Higher or lower level?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm an objective-c programmer and I'm wondering how low should I go (methods wise).

For example, there's NSURL then CFURL (which is lower).  I'm not sure whether using lower or higher levels will add more functionality, or are faster.

Comment: If one of the answers you would accept is "lower", then taking it to its logical conclusion, you should be writing in assembly language.

Comment: What functionality do you need? How much more performance? Usually, optimizing before you've even begun programming is not a good strategy.

Comment: "Always use the highest-level abstraction available to you, and drop down to lower-level abstractions when measurement shows that they are needed." - Chris Hanson http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=232

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Foundation` (`NSURL`) framework classes are often based on the code in `CoreFoundation` (`CFURL`).

With `CF` types you generally work with opaque structs, operating on the data by using related functions. If you needed to write pure c code then you would need to use `CF`. Otherwise these can be a bit clunky and difficult to use in places.

Objective-C classes also allow you to do additional thing like add categories etc.

**Toll-Free bridging**

There are times when you may need to mix and match your code slightly and it's handy to know that a lot of types can simply be cast. e.g. an `NSString` could be used instead of an `CFStringRef`

An example of when I had to do this recently was when I needed to do some url encoding (the `NSString` `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` didn't quite cut it) . The function required `CFStringRef`'s, but with a simple cast I could use my `NSString`'s

```
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                        (CFStringRef)stringToEncode, // <- NSString
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef)encodeChars,    // <- NSString
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
```

Generally you can get away with and **you should** where possible use the `Foundation` classes (higher level of abstraction) as they will most likely provide the same functionality. There will of course be different scenarios where this is not the case, like the url encoding I had to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing an objective-c app, use the objective-c version. In general the CF versions exist so that applications written in C and C++ can communicate with the system APIs.

There are also a few cases where the CF versions give you finer control (eg, the CF collections can be configuted to store arbitrary pointers, rather than just objective-c objects). When you need that kind of finer control, check out the CF version. Otherwise the objective-c version will almost always be what you want. In general the usefulness of their being 'lower-level' is more a case of their being more flexible (with a corresponding increase in complexity) than faster.

(fwiw, any difference in speed will between the two will be in the order of nanoseconds, and if you do need to optimise at any point, it's unlikely that switching from NS- to CF- will be the answer)